# What is the proper way to stop a service running as foreground

Tags: android, foreground-service

I am trying to stop a service which is running as foreground service.

The current issue is that when I call `stopService()` the notification still stays.

So in my solution I have added a receiver which I am registering to inside the `onCreate()`

Inside the `onReceive()` method I call `stopforeground(true)` and it hides the notification.
And then `stopself()` to stop the service.

Inside the `onDestroy()` I unregistered the receiver.

Is there a more proper way to handle this? because stopService() simply doesn't work.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
  unregisterReceiver(receiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: u need to bind service with activity...

Comment: can you show your `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: @user3110424 I have posted it, there is nothing special inside the on destroy, it seems to work fine.

I am asking if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: @AnilBhatiya the service is supposed to run long after the activity has been destroyed, binding it to an activity is not really needed.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

1. From your activity, call `startService(intent)` and pass it some data representing a key to **stop the service**.
2. From your service, call `stopForeground(true)`
3. and then `stopSelf()` right after it.

Comment: inside the onDestroy()?

Comment: @user1940676, no, just from the point where you wish to stop it and remove the notification

Comment: stopforeground is a service method, I don't think if I can or should call it from an activity.

Comment: @user1940676 You need to call it from the service it self. You need some how to tell him that he need to finish him self. You can pass data on intent, it will be received Service.onStart()

Comment: yea that is what I was thinking, just call startservice() with an extra.

Comment: This does not work for me. I can't understand why :(

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to start a service from Broadcast receiver in Android Oreo?

Comment: The downside to stopping a Foreground Service in `startService(...)` with intent data is that you'll need to check if the Foreground Service is running which requires deprecated code not meant for production - [How to determine if an Android Service is running in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452466/how-to-determine-if-an-android-service-is-running-in-the-foreground/56499477#56499477)

Comment: is there a specific benefit to the order of calls? Is it important to do `stopForeground` first, before `stopSelf`?

Comment: This does not seem to work for IntentService started by context.startForegroundService() from a BroadcastReceiver.  The notification still shows the associated app is running.

Comment: Is it mandatory to call stopForeground() ?? only calling stopSelf() is not sufficient ?? In my case, i'm just calling stopSelf() and it is working, notification is being removed.

Comment: its not working for `MediaLibraryService`. look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76231883/how-to-stop-medialibraryservicemedia3-android/76231966#76231966)

Comment: I have some problems with this solution. Sometime the app crashes with an `IllegalStateException` or an `BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException ` with the reason the app is in background.
Is there a way to avoid these?

Comment: Yeah, try startForgroundService, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47654126/1129332, also it requires extra permissions in the Manifest. If you can use jobs instead of services, it is much better

Answer (score 69):

to start and stop a foreground service from an activity use :

```
//start
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForegroundService.class);
    startIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
    startService(startIntent);
//stop
    Intent stopIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForegroundService.class);
    stopIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
    startService(stopIntent);
```

in your foreground service - use (at least) this code:

```
@Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
        // your start service code
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals( Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Stop Foreground Intent");
    //your end servce code
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelfResult(startId);
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: I'd rather return `START_NOT_STICKY` in case of `STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION`.

Comment: stopSelfResult() is important and it makes sure we correctly stop the service.

Comment: Calling startService() to stop a Service ... obviously :D. Anyway, thanks, it helped a lot !

Answer (score 15):

As stated here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Stopping

A started service must manage its own lifecycle. That is, the system doesn't stop or destroy the service unless it must recover system memory and the service continues to run after **onStartCommand()** returns. The service must stop itself by calling **stopSelf()**, or another component can stop it by calling **stopService()**.

Once requested to stop with **stopSelf() or stopService()**, the system destroys the service as soon as possible.

So you can call stopService() from the activity that you used to call startService().
I have done that right here:

```kotlin
start_button.setOnClickListener {
            applicationContext.startForegroundService(Intent(this, ServiceTest::class.java))
        }
stop_button.setOnClickListener {
            applicationContext.stopService(Intent(this, ServiceTest::class.java))
        }
```

I created two buttons to start and stop the service and it works.

Answer (score 14):

From Activity

```
 stopService(new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class));
```

From Service itself

```
  stopForeground(true);
  stopSelf()
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other answers i ended with this snippet using android oreo and laters to stop job services.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
intent.setAction(status);
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(getApplicationContext(), intent);
```

And in service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  startForeground(121, notification);
  if (intent.getAction().equals("StopService")) {
    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();
  }
```

startForeground() is mandatory unless app will crash without calling it

> The new Context.startForegroundService() method starts a foreground
>   service. The system allows apps to call
>   Context.startForegroundService() even while the app is in the
>   background. However, the app must call that service's
>   startForeground() method within five seconds after the service is
>   created.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop service and then update notification, you can first call stopSelf() and then notify(). stopForeground(false) makes the notification cancelable.

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver myBgWorkCompleteReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            stopSelf();
            notificationLayoutExpanded.setTextViewText(R.id.file_download_notify_download_percentage, "Background work completed");
            manager.notify(mNotificationId, notification);
            stopForeground(false);
        }
};


 public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // cancel any running threads here
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(myBgWorkCompleteReceiver);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best way to stop a service is to make stop itself. This way you are sure it actually will stop and preserve data integrity. If you want to do it from outside (activity) I usually use a global static attribute.

Check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57833370/7795547

Answer (score 0):

- You can **stop service** from *service* or *activity*

**From service:**

```
 stopForeground(true);
 stopSelf();
```

**From activity:**

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
//MyService is your service
```

Comment: Do you need to do both or one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a task that runs from time to time (periodically) in the foreground, for example with System.Threading.Timer, you should modify the timer so that it stops periodically executing a method.

One way to 'stop' the timer:

```
if (timer != null)
{
timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Start the service with an action or extra.

   ```
    val intent = Intent(context, AlarmService::class.java)
    intent.setAction("STATE_STOP")
    context.startService(intent)
   ```
2. Based on that action call stopForground(true) and stopSelf()

   ```
    val action = intent?.action.orEmpty()
    if (action == "STATE_STOP"){
        stopForeground(true)
        stopSelf()
    }
   ```