# stopForeground(true) called from onDestroy() doesn't remove a notification

Tags: android

I want to remove a notification after my foreground service is being destroyed. I tried to call `stopForeground(true)` from `onDestroy()` and from `unbind()`. Although onUnbind() and onDestroy() were called(I can see it from logs) notification is still there. I stop the service by calling `unbindService(playerConnection)` and `stopService(this)` from my activity.

Why it's not working this way? Any ideas on how to remove a notification when service is destroyed?

UPATE: one interesting thing I've noticed when playing around with the notification. I've made a special method inside the service:

```
fun hideNotification() {
    stopForeground(true)
    Log.d("PlayerService", "hideNotification")
}
```

Than I call it from my activity when the button is pressed. And it removes the notification. But the same function being called from activity's onStop() or service's onUnbind() or onDestroy() doesn't. I can't understand what the difference between these situations.

Comment: Did you resolve this?
I seem to be having the same problem

Comment: Have you tried this on different android OS versions?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when trying to stop a foreground service and remove all it's notification.

As a workaround i **delete the notification channel** and recreate it if needed.

What solved it to me was to do as follows:

1. Stop the service from within it in onStartCommand() (or elsewhere within the service).
2. StopForeground(true)
3. Remove notification channel (this what actually cleaned all the notifications).

Example:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        var stopService : Boolean  # Service stop condition
        var isRunning : Boolean  # stopSelf() raise exception if service is not running.
        if (stopService}){
            stopForeground(true)
            notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel("channel_id");
            if (isRunning){
                Log.d(TAG, "Service is running, stopping.")
                stopSelf()
            }else
                Log.d(TAG, "Service is not running, no need to stop.")
            return START_NOT_STICKY
        }
```

Some references:
[How to remove old notification channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801940/how-to-remove-old-notification-channels)
[What is the proper way to stop a service running as foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857120/what-is-the-proper-way-to-stop-a-service-running-as-foreground)

Comment: creation of notification channel is after or equal to api level 26, yet the notification doesn't get removed even prior to that

Answer (score 1):

After hours of debugging between 2 services, one that removed the notification and the other that doesn't, I found that the only difference between them is that one of them has the android attribute exported to false.

```
 <service
        ...
        ...
        android:exported="false">
```

I ignore the reason why setting exported to false make me able to remove the notificatión but I wanted to share this solution

Comment: I am still not able to make it work using  android:exported="true" but I found the following:

1- This happens for Samsung devices, other devices (like Google Pixel) work correctly.
2- The notification is correctly removed after calling stopForeground(true), but another notification is created immediately after.

Answer (score 0):

For me main root cause was that I was updating notification from my background thread and calling `stopForeground(true);` was not working because thread was taking time to stop and `stopForeground(true);` was getting called before thread completion. Inside thread I was calling `NotificationManager.notify()` which was updating my notification in notification panel and it was preventing my notification to get clear even after `stopForeground(true);` call.

So cut to short ensure not to call `NotificationManager.notify()` after `stopForeground(true);`

Answer (score -4):

For removing Notification you have to use notificationManager.cancel(ID); in onDestry() or when ever you want to remove notification.

ID: which ever ID used for displaying notification, same ID need to given in cancel()

Ex:
ID = 210;

notificationManager.notify(ID, notification); ==> For display notification.

notificationManager.cancel(ID) ===> For removing notification.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for comment but it's not working. I start the notification with startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification) call. So it supposed to be dismissed with stopForeground(true) call. Moreover, stopForeground indeed works if I call it from separate method before onDestroy. See update.