# How to remove old notification channels?

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo, notification-channel

My app now has 3 notification channels, I want to remove 2 of them.
I thought simply not registering 2 channels would do the trick but when I open the notification settings on the Android device, the old channels still appear.
Is it possible to remove them? 
They have no use and can confuse the users.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Notification channels stay forever once they are created.

To remove them again, simply call [`deleteNotificationChannel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#deleteNotificationChannel(java.lang.String)) on the NotificationManager with the ID of the channel you want to delete:

```
notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel("channel_id");
```

Comment: Thank you. it works. Just FYI Android adds 'x categories deleted' message on the app notifications screen.

Comment: @SagiLow Did you find any solution to remove  'x categories deleted' ?

Comment: @deraxnumber sorry, no luck

Comment: @SagiLow https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S-Phones/Categories-deleted-in-notification-settings/td-p/1277742