# Stop a foreground service on destroy of the activity

Tags: android, service, lifecycle

I would like to use a foreground service in my application. I managed to start it using **startForeground(FOREGROUND_SERVICE_ID, notification)** in my service class.

However, I want my service be killed when app is killed (= onDestroy() of my activity). However, using **stopForeground(true)** and **stopSelf()** doesn't seem to work if I call it from the onDestroy of my activity. However, it works if I call this from the onStart() method.

Is it possible to kill the foreground service when the app is killed and not only stopped ?

I used intent to use my service from my activity like this : http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/

Thank you for your answers and don't hesitate if you need more precisions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20857343/4778343

Comment: Activity `onDestroy` does not mean the app was killed.  It could be a configuration change.

Comment: When you force close your app from running app it will not called onDestroy or onStop

Comment: OK ! So how can I detect when I close my app from running app and then stop my foreground service ?