# When i call stopForeground in api level 19 then service will destroy

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service, api-versioning

When i call stopForeground in api level 19 then service will destroy but when i call stopForeground in api level 24 then service will not destroy
can anyone help me to find out this scenario in api level 20 ,21 , 22 and 23?

Comment: Have you gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857120/what-is-the-proper-way-to-stop-a-service-running-as-foreground/20857343)?

Comment: i test it in emulator with api level 23, 22 its working, now i am downloading 21 and 20 then check it

Comment: now i test 21 and 20 api its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What flag are you providing stopForground(int) docs state that using STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE although unclear mention it could destroy the service.

You could try using the flag STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH and manually delete the notification if no longer required through the NotificationManager.

Docs for reference : [stopForground(int) flags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE)