# How to stop MediaLibraryService:media3 android

Tags: android, kotlin, foreground-service, android-media3

I want to stop a foreground service which extends MediaLibrarySession only after clicking a specific button on the activity, so i tried :

```
val serviceIntent = Intent(this@PartyHostActivity, PlayerService::class.java)
stopService(serviceIntent)
```

and

```
val serviceIntent = Intent(this@PartyHostActivity, PlayerService::class.java)
startService(serviceIntent)
stopService(serviceIntent)
```

but none of them stops the service, `onDestroy` function on the MediaLibraryService was never invoked!!!!why?!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i had two threads running on the service and i didn't invoke `release()` methods for the `session` and the `player` so `stopForeground()` and `stopSelf()` didn't work. i tried creating a method to stop and release all and invoked the method on the `onStartCommand` method with the action `"STOP_SERVICE"` like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76231966/7337499) and `onDestroy()` has been called successfully

Answer (score 0):

The `stopService()` method may not stop the service immediately.

In the case of a foreground service, you need to explicitly call `stopForeground(true)` within the service's code to remove the service from the foreground and allow it to be stopped. This will trigger the `onDestroy()` method in your `MediaLibraryService`.

In your activity:

```kotlin
// Start the service
val serviceIntent = Intent(this@PartyHostActivity, PlayerService::class.java)
startService(serviceIntent)

// Stop the service when the specific button is clicked
specificButton.setOnClickListener {
    val stopIntent = Intent(this@PartyHostActivity, PlayerService::class.java)
    stopIntent.action = "STOP_SERVICE"
    startService(stopIntent)
}
```

In your `MediaLibraryService`:

```kotlin
class PlayerService : Service() {
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if (intent?.action == "STOP_SERVICE") {
            // Stop the foreground service and allow it to be stopped
            stopForeground(true)
            stopSelf()
        } else {
            // Start the foreground service
            // Perform other necessary operations
        }
        return START_STICKY
    }
    // override other functions as you wish

}
```

By sending an intent with the action "STOP_SERVICE", you can differentiate the request to stop the service from other start requests. Within the `onStartCommand()` method, you check for this action and then call `stopForeground(true)` and `stopSelf()` to stop the service properly.

Comment: I'm extending `MediaLibraryService` not `Service` and the solution doesn't work!